# SQL - 3 rows concat to 1

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have 3 rows

```
col_id | colA  | colB | colC
  1    |  a3d  | NULL | NULL
  1    |  NULL | bgq2 | NULL
  1    |  NULL | NULL | upzh
```

This is what I need

```
 col_id | colA | colB | colC
   1    |  a3d | bgq2 | upzh
```

I am using Redshift

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select
  max(colA) as colA,
  max(colB) as colB,
  max(colC) as colC
from <TABLE_NAME>
group by col_id
```

Comment: I have to create a data model. Is this an optimal solution?

Comment: The optimal solution would be to normalize your data with 5nf.